# Fix spacing in math mode

Tags: spacing

Sometimes it's annoying that LaTeX stretches and shrinks formulas in math mode. I know that one can prevent that with ${ ... }$, but I have a big document (~100 pages) and I don't want to check every formula and fix it (not to mention complication of the code). So, is there a way to just fix spacing for every formula? I don't think that overall result will be so bad as long as I use microtype package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a small compilable document illustrating clearly your problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\thinmuskip=1\thinmuskip
\medmuskip=1\medmuskip
\thickmuskip=1\thickmuskip
```

will remove the stretch component.

I'd expect this to look a bit odd though on tight or loose lines where the inter-word spacing stretches or shrinks but the math spacing is fixed. Perhaps you want to do the same to word spacing, but that will be asking a lot of microtype to still justify the lines.