# How to fix inline math spacings as in a normal math display?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath, inline, displaystyle

I would like to fix the horizontal math spacings, when any math expression is shown inside a block of text, without acting on the text itself.  The maths spacings should be exactly the same as in a normal displayed equation (when it is shown between paragraphs).  See for example the following MWE :

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
%\thinmuskip=1\thinmuskip % Solution from another question
%\medmuskip=1\medmuskip  % Solution from another question
%\thickmuskip=1\thickmuskip  % Solution from another question

\begin{document}

Bla bla bla $r(t) = | \, c \, \Delta t + a \, |$, blabla bla.  Blabla bla bla $t < \tensor{t}{_{\mathcal{P}}} - t_0$ Blabla $\mathcal{P}$, bla bla blablabla blabla bla $t > \tensor{t}{_{\mathcal{P}}}$ bla bla bla blabla blabla $\mathcal{P}$.  Blabla bla $t = \tensor{t}{_{\mathcal{P}}}$ Blabla bla blablabla blabla.

Bla bla bla ${r(t) = | \, c \, \Delta t + a \, |}$, blabla bla.  Blabla bla bla ${t < \tensor{t}{_{\mathcal{P}}} - t_0}$ Blabla $\mathcal{P}$, bla bla blablabla blabla bla ${t > \tensor{t}{_{\mathcal{P}}}}$ bla bla bla blabla blabla $\mathcal{P}$.  Blabla bla ${t = \tensor{t}{_{\mathcal{P}}}}$ Blabla bla blablabla blabla.

\end{document}
```

I need a global command at the preamble level, not individual `${...}$` (local level).  Using the commands from the answer [Fix spacing in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540660/fix-spacing-in-math-mode) appears to fix the issue.  But I'm wondering if there's another way, from a specific command to fix the inline math horizontal spacings, in a similar way to `\everymath{\displaystyle}`.  Also, I don't want to affect the normal displayed equations between any block of text.

So is the commented out solution the only one available at the preamble level?

Comment: Are you sure there is an issue to fix? while I'm sure the referenced answer is excellent I'd never use it.  The spacing in displayed math is the same as inline math (including the stretch components) it is just that things are more likely to stretch inline as part of line breaking, basically display math is like inline math in a `center` where the stretch glue at the sides similarly makes it less likely the finite stretch around operators is used.

Comment: Also shouldn't you also fix the inter-word space to a fixed amount? It seems _very_ strange to allow inter-word white space to stretch but not allow the white space in mathematics on the same line.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I'm having the same issue (apparently) as the other guy for which you gave an answer.  I'm using the microtype package, and all of the text spacings are (mostly) very beautiful.  However, I hate it when LaTeX stretches or compresses my math expressions ; they look awful.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, sorry, just forget the compilation issue:  apparently, copying/pasting the code from my Web browser into my LaTeX editor creates an issue!

Comment: I really can't see how this can ever improve the spacing. (not that inline math will look usable with \displaystyle forced)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I use displaystyle for inline equations because I want all the indices and exponents to stay the same as in the bigger equations shown between text paragraphs.  I also want the horizontal spacing to be the same.  I'm only typing small math expressions inline.  Never "big" expressions.

Comment: with \displaystyle you are _very_ limited in what you can do without disturbing line spacing (your example here gets lucky) if you really get lucky in all cases then OK. For horizontal spacing I think this is based on a misunderstanding: the same horizontal space is used in display and inline math.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, ok.  But I don't want the text to have any effect on the inline math spacings.  I need them to stay the same as if they were displayed between the text paragraphs.  The text spacings should be variable in the normal way, but the inline math spacings should stay the same as if they were displayed under the text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119959/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-cham).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I'm tempting another question: what is the preamble equivalent global command of using ${}$ for all inline expression?  Is it the same as your solution?

Comment: isn't that a duplicate of this one? that plus setting \binpenalty and \relpenalty to 10000 to avoid line breaks

Comment: Sorry I don't understand these.  I don't know what medskip and the likes are.  I'm not a typograph!

Comment: Well we have already given this answer twice, if you ask the question again then I would expect the question is closed as duplicate, unless you can phrase it to really ask something different.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I just want to know if your solution is doing exactly the same as using ${}$, or if it's doing something different.  That's all.

Comment: I give up: we've been round this loop a thousand times:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, sorry but it's not clear to me.  I'm just asking Yes or No, if it's doing the same.  This isn't a difficult question!

Comment: it depends what you mean by "same" it works differently and it has a theoretical difference on display math, but as I commented multiple times in the associated chat it is rather unlikely to make any difference on display math in practice.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, so just to conclude (sorry if I'm dense!).  Using $\displaystyle{}$ inline would *essentially* give the same output as using in the preamble the commands \everymath{\displaystyle}
\thinmuskip=1\thinmuskip
\medmuskip=1\medmuskip
\thickmuskip=1\thickmuskip, is that right?  (please, just say Yes or No !).

Comment: if you add `\binoppenalty=10000 \relpenalty=10000` then yes

Comment: Oh?  Then what are these guys?

Comment: for the 100000th time: `{...}` prevents line breaking as well as freezing the spacing, the muskip commands freeze the spacing and the penalty commands stop line breaking. Doing both sets is similar to using `${...}$` for every inline math (and produces the same bad output in general)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I then suggest that you offer all this as an answer.  I'll then be able to up vote and give you the credits.  But about your last comment: my output isn't bad at all, on the contrary it is fully good to my eyes!  I just wanted to do it at the preamble level, instead of using $\displaystyle{}$, so I could change my mind later...